# pthread_create uses 0 as attribute parameter

Tags: multithreading, pthreads

I'm debugging a legacy code at the moment, and this code is using pthread_create() on Linux environment.

Instead of using NULL or attr, it is using 0 for 2nd parameter. I have read the main page: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_attr_init.3.html  and it doesn't mention the use of 0 or interger as attribute parameter.

The actual code is as following:

```
pthread_t hndThread_IPv4;
int pthread_create_ret = pthread_create(&hndThread_IPv4, 0, PushPackageToClient, pStatusTable);
pthread_detach(hndThread_IPv4);
```

My question is does this usage of 0 attribute affect the thread in anyway ?

This thread is having the problem of occasionally crashing/disappearing when calling SQLFreeHandle() to close DBStatement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, an `0` in pointer context is a null pointer constant, so this is just passing `NULL` as the second parameter, meaning that the thread is created with default attributes.